# ring method of finding volume of solid revolution

Tags: integration

Find the volume of the solid figure generated by rotating the area of region bounded by $y=4x-1$ and the x-axis on $[0,3]$ about y_axis?
I tried solving this using ring methode this way 
[image]
But the answer in my book is 21pi/16 
Is my solution wrong? 
Btw I solved the question using cone volume formula which came out to be 36pi as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formulation of the exercise is not very clear. What is the region bounded by the line and the $x$-axis on [0,3]? If the area of $a)$ in the following image is meant, then yes, $36\pi$ is correct, (for rotation around $y$-axis).

[image]

I would have interpreted the description to refer to an area such as $b)$. The rotation volume of b) has a volume of $\left(63-\frac{1}{24}\right) \pi$, which is also not the suggested solution. I was not able to find an area in this picture with that volume.